# Can I run WLST script generated from wl12.1.2.0 config.xml file for configuring wl12.1.3.0 domain?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I am trying to create a WebLogic 12.1.3.0 domain through WLST script. Instead of writing a WLST script, I have generated a configuration script using 'configToScript()' command in WLST tool, which generates a configuration script reading the config.xml file of the existing domain(i.e. 12.1.2.0). My query is that, is it possible to use this script to configure domain for 12.1.3.0 as the generated script doesn't contain any reference to 12.1.2.0 and seems like a generic one?

Comment: Unless you are using features that have changed dramatically, It should work. Best way to find out is to try it out !

Comment: Thank you. There are no changes apart from the version change. I cannot try this out as it needs approvals. But I'll try to run and see somehow. I'll post the result here